# IBM Cognos prompt value when not entered

Tags: cognos

I have a problem in report studio. please help me to figure this out..
i have a optional prompt, i want to check whether the value is selected or not..

Please help how to check..

```
 if (?parameter? is null ) then ('1') else ('2')
 or
 if (ParamDisplayValue('parameter') is null ) then ('1') else ('2')
```

Both the above are not working.. 
Suppose if i select any value in the prompt then the else part works and i get the result as 2, if i wont select anything then i'm not getting the result as 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [In cognos, could we avoid an optional prompt asking a value when its parameter is used in a data item in a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441522/in-cognos-could-we-avoid-an-optional-prompt-asking-a-value-when-its-parameter-i)

Comment: Can you tell us where you are using this expression? Is it a Data Item, a variable, text item expression etc? Some functions are available in one expression type and not others. For instance ParaDisplayValue won't work in data item expressions or filters.

Comment: Hi John, i want to use this in the filter expression... There are three level of prompts.. I should validate which prompt is entered and which is not.. so pls help..

Answer (score 0):

My guess, without doing extensive testing, is that an empty optional prompt doesn't exist at all and can't be compared to null. That said, I believe there's an easy fix.

Since you know that when you select an item '?parameter? is null' will return false, '?parameter? is not null' should return true and you can reverse the logic:

```
if (?parameter? is not null) then ('2') else ('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a conditional block. Set a block variable of type boolean with this expression:

```
ParamDisplayValue('myParam') is null
```

Then go to your conditional block again switch property "current block" to yes/no.
When yes (meaning that our block variable is true so the parameter is null) add a text item and just write "All".

When no add a text item with source type as report expression and write `ParamDisplayValue('myParam')`

P.S: there is also a way to count how many values the user selected (so as not to display all of them 1 by 1 but just show "62 values selected") but it needs some javascript and a hidden prompt field.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ParamCount`

More details here:

http://joesanswers.blogspot.com.au/2008/09/checking-for-empty-parameters-in-cognos.html

Comment: What happens if you show the actual value of ParamCount on your page? is it 0 or something else? Does it have any correlation with whether you select a parameter or not?